# Filter Icon in Network tab is showing as Red in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome

When I am trying to get the request in the left hand section of the network tab , the filter icons always shows in red color and lots of other links also get loaded, which makes finding the request harder. But in some YouTube videos, I have seen the filter icon shows in blue color and only the request data shows in the left hand side. Can anybody explain why I am getting this scenario and how can I fix this ??
chrome Version:  63.0.3239.132

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When the filter icon is red, it means you have deviated from the default filter settings. It's just an indicator of a change, much like the usage of an asterisk in a modified document.

When the filter icon is blue, it uses the default settings - i.e. nothing entered in the filter input, "Hide data URLs" is un-checked, and "All" requests are selected.

To reduce the number of requests shown, select an appropriate filter. You can type into the input field to narrow down your choices, with support for Regex matching too.

Read the full capabilities of [Request filtering](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filter) in the DevTools docs.